# Is .#{$pretty--class-name} a sass interpolation method?

Tags: sass, string-interpolation

I [found a nice page](https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/) for displaying switches (checkboxes, radio, slider etc.). 
It's been a while since I coded html/sass and I'm a bit baffeled over this bit `.#{$pretty--class-name}`.

I thought you either used dot or hash. But here you use both. 
Is this a SASS specific thing where it replaces `#{$pretty--class-name}` with a variable name?

I found this bit [in the SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#advanced-variable-functions):

> Users occasionally want to use interpolation to define a variable name
>   based on another variable. Sass doesn’t allow this, because it makes
>   it much harder to tell at a glance which variables are defined where.
>   What you can do, though, is define a map from names to values that you
>   can then access using variables.

But below example is not using the same method.

```
$pretty--class-name: pretty !default;

.#{$pretty--class-name} {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: But the syntax `#{variable-name}`, is that SASS?

Comment: Put your answer as comment and I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you mentioned refers only to create variables on fly based on another variables and this is not possible in SASS: you have to use a map to do something similar. In your case, there is only an interpolation method to create a class, not another SASS variable.

So `.#{$pretty--class-name}` is an example of [SASS interpolation syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) that generates `.pretty` class.

**P.S.** By the way, that page is really nice. Thanks for sharing it!